# SQL number decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I run a query and all my numbers are coming out to 5 decimal points:

for example -

```
156713.55000
2103613.03000
2080.08000
```

is there a simple piece of code I can add into my code so the 'Cost' table results are to 2 decimal points?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this? SQL-Server? MYSQL? Also, please post a table definition, or at the very least tell us what the column is called in the `Cost` table, and what datatype it is.

Comment: If this is a currency value that can only have two decimal places then there should be at most 2 decimal places in the column, structuring your table / database so that incorrect values cannot be added by default is _always_ preferable to converting them to the "correct" value on exit from the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following example will help you.

With rounding:

```
select ROUND(55.4567, 2, 0)
-- Returns 55.4600

select CAST(55.4567 as decimal(38, 2))
-- Returns 55.46
```

Without rounding:

```
select ROUND(55.4567, 2, 1)
-- Returns 55.4500

select CAST(ROUND(55.4567, 2, 1) as decimal(38, 2))
-- Returns 55.45
```

or

Use `Str()` Function. It takes three arguments(the number, the number total characters to display, and the number of decimal places to display

```
  Select Str(12345.6789, 12, 3)
```

displays:  '   12345.679'  ( 3 spaces, 5 digits 12345, a decimal point, and three decimal digits (679). - it rounds if it has to truncate

for a Total of 12 characters, with 3 to the right of decimal point.

Comment: +1 for `STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the `ROUND` function:

```
SELECT ROUND(column, 2) FROM Cost
```

Or to strip the decimals and round, use `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST(column as decimal(10, 2))
```